# Finding value of a specific tag with attribute value in XML

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I am trying to parse an rss/atom XML using C#.

Each XML can have multiple `<entry>` tags and each `entry` can be like this.

```
<entry>
    <id>232323232</id>
    <published>2020-03-09T00:00:00.000-04:00</published>
    <updated>2020-03-09T08:54:24.347-04:00</updated>
    <category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="tour" />
    <title type='text'>LOre ipsum</title>
    <content type='html'>lorem ipsum
    </content>
    <link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml'
        href='http://loremipsum.blog/comments/default'
        title='Post Comments' />
    <link rel='replies' type='text/html'
        href='http://loremipsum.blog/blog.html#comment-form'
        title='5 Comments' />
    <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml'
        href='http://loremipsum.blog/posts/default/4452478062189390152' />
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
        href='http://loremipsum.blog/posts/default/4452478062189390152' />
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
        href='http://loremipsum.blog/blog.html'
        title='Poison - Test Blog' />
    <author>
        <name>Bookish</name>
        <uri>http://loremipsum.blog/profile/12345</uri>
        <email>noreply@blogger.com</email>
        <gd:image rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail' width='32' height='32'
            src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/something/bookishbutton.jpg' />
    </author>
    <media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
        url="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/something/poison.jpg"
        height="72" width="72" />
    <thr:total>5</thr:total>
</entry>
```

My C# code to select values from these is something like this

```
feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants("entry")
        select new
        {
            Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
            Link = feed.Element("link").Value, //<-- this is where I want to focus on
            Description = feed.Element("content").Value,
            PublishDate = feed.Element("published").Value
        };
```

As there are multiple `<link>` tags inside each `<entry>`, I want to specifically fetch `href` value for `<link rel='alternate'>`.

In this case, my result should be `http://loremipsum.blog/blog.html`

Comment: maybe `feed.Elements.First(e=>e.Name == "link" && e.Attribute("rel").Value == "alternate")`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working with `XElement`'s you can try querying attributes. Something to get you started:

```cs
var feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants("entry")
    select new
    {
        Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
        Link = feed.Elements("link")
            .FirstOrDefault(le => le.Attribute("rel")?.Value == "alternate" )
            ?.Attribute("href").Value,
        Description = feed.Element("content").Value,
        PublishDate = feed.Element("published").Value
    };
```